# Why do MFC .rc files sometimes have a manually inserted \0 at the end?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

[Within this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(v=VS.85).aspx), I notice that \0 is inserted into the #define statements for building version strings.  I've also seen it in some MFC projects that I am maintaining.  While going through the process of moving version resources into a .rc2 file where I can use one header include to setup the versions across all of my projects I've noticed the \0.  In some cases it causes no problems, but in some cases the properties window of the resulting compiled file will show a trailing quote (").  Removing the \0 doesn't seem to hurt anything, but I don't understand why they would ever be needed.  Hopefully there are some old school MFC gurus that understand this that can explain whether removing the \0 is recommended or not.

Example:

```
    VALUE "FileVersion", VERSION_STR"\0" // <-- adding it here causes the version to show in the properties dialog as 1, 0, 4, 1" which is odd.  
    VALUE "InternalName", "DaHelper\0" // <-- what is the \0 for? Isn't it already a string literal null terminated without adding \0?
```

Comment: The strings are inserted exactly as entered in the RC file (no terminating zero).  If when you process them you need to string(s) to be zero terminated you need to include the zero in the resource string.

Comment: So why isn't the key null terminated then?  Looking at dialog resources, I see no additional \0 within quotes.  In the microsoft example they add the \0 in a macro definition.  Isn't that a string literal that is already null terminated?  That's just standard C/C++.

Comment: No it's a RC file - different rules.

Answer (score 1):

May be nobody has a real answer for it.

Also the documentation shows no rule for it.
The [samples in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx) (your link) show the same defines, when using strings. Only a few are shown. But I rechecked real old sources sind 16bit times. It was always the same. The VALUE types are all terminated by a \0 character. Seams that the string defines in the resource editor for this type of resource is not automatically \0 terminated.